# How to create Session Variable in custom PHP file and pass to Header

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I'm currently trying to pass a SESSION variable from a custom file create_token.php to my header.php file. The create_token is stored in my child theme directory along with my header file.

I've started the session in my functions.php file as well.

```
if (!session_id()) {
 session_start();
}
```

I've started my SESSION in the create_token file like so:

```
$_SESSION['generated_token'] = 'Cron goes here';
```

I'm simply called the SESSION variable, in my header, like so:

```
print $_SESSION['generated_token'];
```

It is not currently outputting anything. Could I get some advice on how to properly set/pass the session from my custom file to my header file?

Comment: `session_start()` must be in ALL of the files.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I've just added this to my header as well as create_token and it didn't change anything.

Comment: If your _header_ file goes first, and the _create_token_ goes after, then the session variable will never be set. You may need to revise that order matter in your code.

Comment: It is also worth noting that `session_start()` needs to be inserted before a single character (including whitespace and invisible BOM) gets sent to the browser. If anything besides PHP is in the file before this call the headers will already be sent and you won't be able to start the session.